# Optimize #define method

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, c-preprocessor

I define an animation method like this:

```
#define Animation_05(f) [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];(f);[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and use this like:

```
Anmation_05(a.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 10, 150));
Anmation_05(b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, 15, 150));
Anmation_05(c.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 15, 150));
Anmation_05(d.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 15, 150));
```

I want to know,it there a way to optimize the define?Maybe some code like just perform Anmation_05 one time.

Comment: What do you want to optimize it for?

Comment: Why make this a macro at all, why not make it a method, or use blocks...

Comment: ye,use method or blocks is good,but if i use macro,how should it be?